# Where to place the year in a product's name?

Tags: grammaire, nombres, ordre-des-mots, indications-de-temps

Which one of the following phrases is correct translation of the "2013 Mercedes-Benz Sprinter"?

1. 2013 Sprinter de Mercedes-Benz, or
2. Sprinter 2013 de Mercedes-Benz

And if you could give an example of a similar usage, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Bear in mind though that in France (and Europe in general) it's not common to refer to a specific model by its year, at least not to the same extent like in the USA. [Some brands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peugeot_208) increment a numeric value. [Other brands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SEAT_Le%C3%B3n) only renew their model every 4-5 years, reducing the need of disambiguating. [Others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkswagen_Golf_Mk7) even use roman numbers to indicate which generation the model is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, the model's year is always going to come after the model's name. As for the make, it can either be before the model's name, or after the model's year. If it is before, it does not need any particle to link it to the model, but it does need a "*de*" if it is after.

Therefore, both of the following are correct:

> Le Sprinter 2013 de Mercedes-Benz
>
> Le Mercedes-Benz Sprinter 2013

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would I still need "Le" in the beginning if Sprinter is not just a model but also a brand?

Comment: @i-- It would depend on the context, but most likely yes, or another pronoun such a *ce* or *du*. Feel free to ask another question if you want, too! :)

Comment: You could also add *Le Mercedes-Benz Sprinter de 2013*, as a shortcut for *Le Mercedes-Benz Sprinter de l'année 2013*.